# sorting the rows of all components in a list

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have a task to sorting the rows of all components in a list in R. 
Here is what I have tried:

```
chrvector<-c("J","A","G","B","H","E","C","F","D","I")
numvector<-rnorm(1:10)
tentimestenmatrix<-matrix(
  (1:100), 10, 10
  )

mylist<-list(chrvector, numvector, tentimestenmatrix)

mylist[order(sapply(mylist,'[[',1))]
```

however, what I want is should be sorted within each component, then, form a new list. could anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: that goes for the matrix? Sort every row of the matrix? (In your example, rows are sorted already)

Comment: `lapply(mylist, sort)`?

Comment: @h3rm4n that will flatten the matrix

Comment: Wait, sort the rows? So you want sorted rows in the matrix element?

Comment: @h3rm4n, Thanks! that is what I want to do :)